# Convert Polynomial string representation in JS using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, math, polynomial-math

I have a string that contain a polynomial representation. Some examples are given bellow:

```
'1+3x'
'3y+1'
'-2+50x1'
'50x+31x^2-29'
'3.85x^3-2000'
`5x^2+2x+3`
```

Few things to notice:

- The terms do not contain certain order.
- There is only one indeterminate, a lower case letter that may be followed by a number. (eg `x` or `x1`)
- Coefficients may be any real number. In case of zero, the term will not be shown. (eg. `33x^2+x-10.3` or `33x^2+1`)

I want to split each term as a different array element.

```
'1+3x' // => ['1', '+3x']
'3y+1' // => ['3y', '+1']
'-2+50x1' // => ['-2', '+50x1']
'50x+31x^2-29' // => ['50x', '+31x^2', '-29']
'3.85x^3-2000' // => ['3.85x^3', '-2000']
'5x^2+2x+3' // => ['5x^2', '+2x', '+3']
```

To fulfill the above requirement I use the `match()` method of the `String` Object in JS.

This is what I have tried so far: `polynomial.match(/[a-z0-9.^]+(\+|\-)?/gi);`

But I get a slightly different output from what I want.

```
'1+3x' // => ['1+', '3x']
'3y+1' // => ['3y+', '1']
'-2+50x1' // => ['2+', '50x1']
'50x+31x^2-29' // => ['50x+', '31x^2-', '29']
'3.85x^3-2000' // => ['3.85x^3-', '2000']
'5x^2+2x+3' // => ['5x^2+', '2x+', '3']
```

What do I miss in my current solution?

Comment: What if you change the regex to `polynomial.match(/(\+|\-)?[a-z0-9.^]+/gi);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `polynomial.match(/(\+|\-)?[a-z0-9.^]+/gi);`
I hope it works for you

Answer (score 2):

You can probably simplify it to anything followed by non +/-: [`.[^+-]*`](https://regex101.com/r/JJRJ8O/1)

Comment: Nice! Is there any time benefit for smaller regexes?

Comment: In a way yes .. not so much because of the size, but also the complexity. In your case I think the ignore case flag instead of a `A-Z` group, and the capturing group `(\+|\-)` instead of `[+-]` might make it a bit slower. It's more important that it works the way you expect for invalid inputs.